# WPF: Creating Application resource that requires parameter in constructor - how?

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

I am having a problem creating a resource in my App.xaml file.  My problem is that I want to instantiate an object that requires a parameter in its constructor (my Linq-to-Sql DataContext, in this particular case), but I don't know if it's even possible to pass parameters like this in XAML.  Does anyone know of a way to get around this?  I'd like to access this data context within my XAML globally, the idea being that I can pass it as a parameter to ObjectDataSource:

```
   <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="PriceCodeProvider" x:Name="priceCodeProvider" ObjectType="{x:Type local:PriceCodeObjectDataProvider}" >
        <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="MyDataContext" />
        </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
```

From a design standpoint, I'm sure that there are better ways of accomplishing what I'm looking for, but I'm pretty new to WPF... and with a little help, I think this will do the job for my particular project.

Thanks!

-Charles

Answer (score 0):

XAML doesn't allow to pass constructor arguments. You need to create a wrapper class, set properties, then your wrapper can invoke the `ObjectDataProvider` constructor correctly.